# Adding dependencies for a Flutter plugin crashes my Flutter App

Tags: plugins, dependencies, flutter, channel

When I follow the hello-world approach in creating a Flutter plugin and adding it to another hello-world Flutter project, it all fails whenever I try to add the plugin dependency (either local with `path:` or remote with `git:`.

My steps are:

1. I create a new Flutter project, doing the following inside a terminal:

`flutter create hello_world_app`

2. I add a large asset (> 665 MB) to my hello_world_app since I will need it inside my app.
3. I build and run a prototype app using my large asset inside hello_world_app. It runs without any problems.
4. I did create the plugin using the following terminal command:
5. I create a Flutter plugin writing inside a terminal:

`flutter create --org com.mycomp --template=plugin -i swift large_file_copy`

6. I do some minor changes to the newly created plugin. I can run the newly created plugin "large_file_copy" on both worlds (iOS and Android). I run it from the plugin-example folder. All works well.
7. I make a git repo out of the plugin and I commit all changes and push it to a public git repo.

But now, that's when things go wrong:

8. I try to add the plugin to the dependencies of my hello-world project, doing the following:

Inside `pubspec.yaml` of my "hello_world_app"

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  large_file_copy:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/XXXXX/large_file_copy.git
```

The output terminal sais:

```
Running "flutter packages get" in my_app...                     0.6s
exit code 0
```

Then I try to run my project. And that's the moment the App crashes.

WHY IS ADDING THE PLUGIN DEPENDENCY MAKE MY FLUTTER PROJECT CRASH ??

In fact, I can even import the plugin-package to my flutter code and call the plugin method. The compiler does not complain at this moment. But as soon as I try to build and run, that's when the app crashes...

What is wrong in the above approach ??

How do I correctly set the plugin dependency ??

Here are the two error message-logs (one for iOS and one for Android world). Again, these occur as soon as the plugin dependency is added to the pubspec.yaml file....

Error message-log for iOS:

```
2018-12-23 14:32:52.179 xcodebuild[56661:1181076] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID D76765677-CB11-4D25-A34B-E33DB5A7C231 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/KZLinkedConsole.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2018-12-23 14:32:52.179 xcodebuild[56661:1181076] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID D76765677-CB11-4D25-A34B-E33DB5A7C231 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/ColorSenseRainbow.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2018-12-23 14:32:52.179 xcodebuild[56661:1181076] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID D76765677-CB11-4D25-A34B-E33DB5A7C231 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/BBUDebuggerTuckAway.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2018-12-23 14:32:52.180 xcodebuild[56661:1181076] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID D76765677-CB11-4D25-A34B-E33DB5A7C231 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET sqflite OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
/Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/git/large_file_copy-5cc22b5c6d2345ba1ab23a44324b222c68d24ab4/ios/Classes/MyPluginName.m:2:9: fatal error: 'large_file_copy/large_file_copy-Swift.h' file not found
#import < large_file_copy/large_file_copy-Swift.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XS.
Exited (sigterm)
```

.
Error message-log for Android:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Failed to obtain compression information for entry
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 12s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: does it work if you directly refer to the local copy of your plugin with `    path: ../large_file_copy` in the pubspec of your hello world app? (Correct the path as necessary to your project structure.)

Comment: no - same thing, same error... Adding the `path:` does not help! The compiler does not complain when I add the path and also when I import the package. But as soon as I build and run, then that's when the above crashes happen for iOS and Android... (the error messages remain the same for remote-git as for path dependency).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that not the plugin-adding is the problem !

It is rather my large asset that I have inside the Flutter app that causes the exception.

And it must be more or less a coincidence that my Flutter app crashes from the moment I add the plugin to my app. It was misleading. (I therefore assume that it might have done so as well - later when I build-up my Flutter app and add more code. It might be a memory issue of some sort...or you tell me!)

As soon as I remove my large asset (665 MB), the plugin integration works smoothly without any exception.

The question shifts tough to another stackoverflow question: [How to integrate a large asset in my Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922122/how-do-i-integrate-a-large-asset-in-my-flutter-app)

And this query can be closed.